# i am getting an error in the cpanel when uploading a laravel project

Tags: laravel, cpanel

this is the error note it is on cpanel it works in my local host:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?' in
>   /home/hfindcok/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php
>   on line 242

Comment: The line in question (assuming Laravel 5.6) is `return app('cache')->get($arguments[0], $arguments[1] ?? null);`. Is your php version compatible with the Laravel version?

Comment: yes it is and i have changed it to 7.2 in the cpanel now i am getting a blank page but the favicon is showing what is the problem

Comment: There's a number of things that could cause a blank page. Find your apache logs (or server logs) and see if you're getting any errors. Or check `storage/logs/laravel.log` and see if there's anything there.

Comment: thanks for your help i just had to clear the cache

Answer (score 0):

The reason can be you are running the Laravel Project in lower PHP version.
Change the PHP version as compatible with the Laravel version.

Comment: i agree and i have changed that on my cpanel